# Understanding two flags and a dollar sign in a CURL command

Tags: command-line, curl

I right-clicked a `POST` request in Chrome and selected "Copy as cURL".

I got a `curl` command that includes the following:

```
--data-binary $'------WebKitFormBound
```

I am used to seeing `curl` requests that have a single flag and string. Like this:

```
$ curl -0 "output.txt"
```

I understand that the `--data-binary` command will `POST` [binary data](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--data-binary) (presumably after converting the string, after the `--data-binary` switch, into binary). But what does the dollar sign mean?

What does the `curl` request mean if it has two dashes and a dollar sign?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The notation being used there `$'...'` is a special form of quoting a string recognised by a few shells like `ksh` (where it originated), `zsh` and `bash`.

*excerpt*

> Strings that are scanned for ANSI C like escape sequences. The Syntax is
>   $'string'

#### Example

```
$ echo $'hola\n'
hola

$
```

#### References

- [Quotes and escaping](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting)
- [3.1.2.4 ANSI-C Quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html)

Comment: so basically the command says "scan the string for escape characters and print the formatted string then convert that printed string to binary"

Comment: @akh2103 - yes I believe that's how it works.

Answer (score 1):

Part of your question was answered. In answer to the other part, the "two dashes" is typically the long form use of a parameter.

It is common for commands to have both a long and a short form for any given parameter. For example, if you look at the manual for `curl`, you will see:

```
-a, --append
    (FTP  SFTP)  When  used  in  an  upload,  this makes curl...
```

The `-a, --append` means that you can use either `-a` or `--append` in order to use that parameter. The `-a` could be considered an abbreviation. Whether you use one or the other makes no difference, it is personal preference.